# How to implement rowcount properly in a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble retrieving the number of affect rows by my trigger. I am not sure how to implement `@@rowcount` in my trigger so that it can be created and run properly. This trigger essentially is supposed to either delete or insert suppliers into a table and return an aborted or successful message. I need a variable of some sort to count my rows, and that is where I am having issues.

What I have so far, with syntax and context errors:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_limitTotalSupplier 
ON Suppliers_copy
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @R int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Suppliers_copy) > 29
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RAISERROR ('Total suppliers cannot beyond 29. Your INSERT is aborted.', 16,1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        R = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted
        PRINT (R+ ' suppliers are inserted successfully');
    END

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Suppliers_copy) > 29
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RAISERROR ('Total suppliers cannot below 25. Your DELETE is aborted.', 16,1)
    END
    ELSE
        R = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted

    PRINT (R+ ' suppliers are inserted successfully');  
    RETURN
END;
```

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'R'

when I attempt

```
R = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted
```

and

> The name "R" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

on my line:

```
PRINT (R + ' suppliers are inserted successfully');
```

I am not sure what to do. I haven't used `@@rowcount` yet at all because it cause even more errors than this.

Comment: What is "`R`"? A statement cannot start with an object's name, especially when that object has no scope. I *assume* you mean `@R`, meaning this is just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers should not output messages, except error messages on failure (or perhaps for debugging).  The client will get the normal rowcount message from the DML if the trigger has `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

So this should be simply:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER tgr_limitTotalSupplier 
ON Suppliers_copy
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @R int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Suppliers_copy) > 29
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RAISERROR ('Total suppliers cannot beyond 29. Your INSERT is aborted.', 16,1);
        RETURN;
    END

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Suppliers_copy) < 25
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RAISERROR ('Total suppliers cannot below 25. Your DELETE is aborted.', 16,1);
        RETURN;
    END

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
declare @R int;

select @R = count(*)
from inserted;

print concat(@R, ' suppliers are inserted successfully');
```